# Using String array "constant" in Spring @RequestMapping value

Tags: java, spring, controller, constants

I should probably point out that Spring is not in and of itself necessarily crucial to this question, but I encountered this behavior while using Spring, so the question uses the situation in Spring in which I encountered this.

I have a controller class that maps requests for `GET` and `POST` requests to the same set of URLs for a particular form. This form has different URLs for different locales, but there is only one method for the `GET` request, and one for the `POST`, since the logic at the controller level for the form is identical for each locale site (but things deeper in the logic, like locale-specific validation, may be different). Example:

```java
@Controller
public class MyFormController {

    // GET request
    @RequestMapping(value={"/us-form.html", "/de-form.html", "/fr-form.html"},
            method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String showMyForm() {
        // Do some stuff like adding values to the model
        return "my-form-view";
    }

    // POST request
    @RequestMapping(value={"/us-form.html", "/de-form.html", "/fr-form.html"},
            method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public String submitMyForm() {
        // Do stuff like validation and error marking in the model
        return "my-form-view"; // Same as GET
    }
}
```

The form `GET` and `POST` works just fine when written like this. You'll notice that the `String` arrays used for the `@RequestMapping` values are identical. What I want to do is put those URLs into one spot (ideally a `static final` field in the controller) so that when we add new URLs (which correspond to the form in future localized sites), we can just add them in one spot. So I tried this modification to the controller:

```java
@Controller
public class MyFormController {

    // Moved URLs up here, with references in @RequestMappings
    private static final String[] MY_URLS =
            {"/us-form.html", "/de-form.html", "/fr-form.html"};

    // GET request
    @RequestMapping(value=MY_URLS, // <-- considered non-constant
            method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String showMyForm() {
        // Do some stuff like adding values to the model
        return "my-form-view";
    }

    // POST request
    @RequestMapping(value=MY_URLS, // <-- considered non-constant
            method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public String submitMyForm() {
        // Do stuff like validation and error marking in the model
        return "my-form-view"; // Same as GET
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler complains about the `value` attribute no longer being a constant. I am aware that Spring requires that `value` must be a constant, but I had thought that using a `final` field (or `static final` in my case) with an `Array` literal containing `String` literals would have passed as "constant". My suspicion here is that the array literal has to be constructed on the fly in such a way that it is uninitialized when the `value` attribute is parsed.

I feel like this shouldn't be a hard thing to figure out with a basic Java knowledge, but something is escaping me that I haven't been able to find any answers for after some research. Can someone confirm my suspicion and give a citation or good explanation for why that may be so, or deny my suspicion and explain what the actual issue is?

Note: I cannot simply combine the URLs into a [Path Pattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns), as each form URL is in its localized site's language, and matching on that would be impossible. I merely give the "/{locale}-form.html" strings above as my URLs for example's sake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The value for annotation attribute RequestMapping.value must be a constant expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213723/the-value-for-annotation-attribute-requestmapping-value-must-be-a-constant-expre)

Comment: @sp00m It may indeed be a duplicate. I wasn't sure if it was a dupe, due to that questioner using a method's return value, as opposed to literals like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this is nothing to do with Spring, all Annotation parameters must be compile-time constants.  That's a basic java language rule.

Marking the array reference as final doesn't cut it because this is still perfectly legal:

```
MY_URLS[0] = "es-form.html";
```

Also, how locked in are you into embedding locale into the url like that in the first place?  Are you emulating legacy links?  Spring has plenty of built in support for using the browser's actual locale.

Comment: Good point about `MY_URLS[0]`, should have thought about the implications of that (I've been deep in JavaScript land lately). Unfortunately I'm locked in to using locale-specific URLs because it is required by the client we're writing this code for, and changing them (if possible in the first place) would be a laborious process (mainly on the client's part, but we would probably get grief of some form from that process). We also have several form URLs following this convention that are already or are about to go live, and changing at the last minute wouldn't be any fun.